# Разработка http-радио-проигрывателя Android

Tags: android, http

Здравствуйте.

Направьте пожалуйста на библиотеки, которые позволят:

1. Получать поток с http
2. Воспроизводить его непосредственно в программе
3. И желательно, как сделать виджет

Точно не знаю, название этого протокола, поэтому приведу дампы данных из сниффера:

Запрос:

```
GET /server.128 HTTP/1.0
Host: radio.server.fm
User-Agent: WinampMPEG/5.61, Ultravox/2.1
Ultravox-transport-type: TCP
Accept: */*
Icy-MetaData:1
Connection: close
```

Ответ:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Content-Type:
audio/mpeg icy-br:128
icy-description:Server.FM
icy-genre:Public Radio icy-name:Server
icy-pub:1 icy-url:http://server.fm
Server: Icecast 2.3.2 Cache-Control:
no-cache icy-metaint:16000
```

Ну а дальше уже идут блоки данных по 1400-1460 байт.
Т.е. обычный http, считывать все это не составит труда, но как это отдать проигрывателю и как достать всю интересующую информацию? Название трека и т.п. Подскажите описание всему этому делу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может пригодиться:

- [Radio-T Client](https://github.com/sergeymo/android-radio-t)
- [Custom Audio Streaming with MediaPlayer](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/)

Comment: Вот спасибочки:) То, что надо.
А что насчет виджетов?

Answer (score 2):

Так это же icecast.. ну так и читайте про этот протокол.. я когда-то сталкивался с ним, но ОЧЕНЬ давно.. к сожалению, ничего не помню уже. Помню, что с документацией дела обстояли как-то не важно и много инфы доставал на каких-то тематических формумах. Это предмет для долгих мучительных раскопок с помощью гугла :)

Попробуйте копнуть тут:

- [Practical: A Shoutcast Server](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-shoutcast-server.html)
- [Протоколы сетевых радиотрансляций Icecast/Shoutcast](http://www.opennet.ru/base/sys/radio_protocols.txt.html)
- [icecast-now-playing-script](http://code.google.com/p/icecast-now-playing-script/)
- [другое](http://icecast.imux.net/viewtopic.php?p=11130)

Comment: Да, копал я все это, но дело в том, что проблема теперь все это под андроид приложить. Да еще и с виджетом в придачу.